# Mule request-reply - why can't we use transactional VM or JMS inside the scope

Tags: mule

[Mule doc](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/request-reply-scope) says that, VM or JMS connectors that are set up to be transactional can’t be used inside a request-reply scope. I do not understand it well.

Can any one please explain it with an example?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?
The URL that you point to explains exactly why it isn't possible.

V*M or JMS connectors that are set up to be transactional can’t be used inside a request-reply scope. Both VM and JMS connectors allow you to perform transactions of several different types, but none of these are compatible with how the request-reply scope works. **This is because the request that is to be sent out by the request-response isn’t sent until the transaction is committed – but the transaction in turn is not committed until the entire flow has been executed (including the execution of the request-response scope). This leads to a situation where both processes are blocking each other: the flow isn’t fully executed because it’s still waiting for the response on the request-reply scope, but this response will never arrive since the request hasn’t been sent yet (as mentioned before, this message is sent only once the transaction is committed)**.*